Young girl about 6 gets father's friend as bodyguard (not Man on Fire)
This movies is bit old and released at least before 2003. 
Girl's father is apparently rich and hire one of his old friend to protect her of some dangers.
In one scene they were attacked by a gang (the girl and the body guard) He fights with them. Girl's been held by one man. Guard says to her "(call her name) you have milk". She has a milk packet in her hand. She drops it and he attacks the man at the same time and rescue. Finally in that scene both of them jump out of a window into a pool. 

You're looking for John Woo's Blackjack from 1998 with Dolph Lundgren, a TV movie that was basically an unpicked pilot.

After saving Casey, a daughter of his friend, from hired assassins, Jack Devlin is hit with a strange phobia - fear of white color. But when his other friend, who works as a bodyguard for a supermodel, is wounded, Jack decides to step in for him. Now he must confront his fear and the assassin, who seems to be well aware of Jack's problem 

The scene you're describing is from the beginning of the movie. The daughter is held at gunpoint while holding a milk carton, and Jack tells her: "Don't worry, you got milk", prompting her to spill the milk on the assassin's arm and slip away from his grip. They then jump into a swimming pool (via trampoline!) to escape the usual fireball. Jack then develops his fear of white - too bad the final fight is in some sort of milk factory... Yeah. :/
Here's the trailer:




Thank you so much. I was looking for this one since 2003. I am from Sri Lanka and this was telecast back in 2003 on state television.
